# What is the most efficient way to notarize and staple a .zip containing a .app?

Tags: xcode, macos, notarize

Currently, an `.app/` folder can't be submitted for notarization and must be packaged first. On the other hand, a ticket can't be stapled to a `.zip` after notarization is successful. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow)

This creates a process as below:

1. Build the application
2. Zip the `.app/`
3. Submit the `.zip` for notarization
4. Unzip the the `.zip`
5. Staple the ticket to the `.app/`
6. Re-zip the `.app/` for distribution

Our specific use case is that our application will initially be installed by users from a `.dmg` while subsequent updates are downloaded through `.zip`. Notarizing the `.dmg` is very straightforward. Zipped contents are another story.

Is there a more efficient method than the steps above?

Comment: I'm unsure why (4) exists... can't you just staple the `.app/` you notarized?

Comment: @dkl you have to zip `.app/` to notarize it. Unless I'm mistaken, you can't staple to the `.app/` while it's still zipped.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but why "Unzip the .zip" after?  You have the original .app.  I just don't understand step (4).

Comment: @dkl Because I thought I had to. This is the meat of the question: "Is there a more efficient method than the steps above?"

Comment: I've successfully done notarization and I do not do (4) and use the app built in (1) for (5) and (6).  I additionally make a `.dmg` and notarize and staple that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No Dan, you've got it. Your use case is similar to mine and that's how I do it. In my case I'm distributing a .pkg that comprises an app, an uninstaller, a couple of kernel extensions, but the concept is the same for just an app. By the way, like your dmg, I'm distributing the pkg for downloads but then zipping that pkg for Sparkle updates.

The process only seems bizarre until you think of the zip file as a way of packaging and submitting the app bundle. You want to notarize the app and staple the resulting notarization to the app bundle. You do it like this:

- Notarize the app by submitting a zipped package of the app bundle.
- When the notarization successfully completes, staple the result to the app bundle.
- Package the app bundle for distribution (in your case by adding it to a dmg).
- Notarize the dmg, and staple to the dmg.

For more convenience: if you do this in a makefile, the make can automatically wait for the notarizations before stapling. I do it like this:

```
notarizationRequestID=$(shell xcrun altool --notarize-app \
                                   --primary-bundle-id com.mycompany.appID \
                                   --username $(DEV_USERNAME)
                                   --password $(DEV_PASSWORD)
                                   --asc-provider $(DEV_PROVIDER) \
                                   --file myApp.app.zip \
              | awk '/RequestUUID/ { print $$NF; }') ;\

while ! xcrun altool --notarization-info $$notarizationRequestID \
                     --username $(DEV_USERNAME)
                     --password $(DEV_PASSWORD)
                     --asc-provider $(DEV_PROVIDER) \
                     --output-format xml \
              | grep -q 'https://osxapps-ssl.itunes.apple.com/itunes-assets' ;\
    do sleep 5 ;\
    echo "." ;\
done ;\
```

If you're distributing an update via Sparkle, you'll also need to gather the app cast metadata so you can paste it into your app cast.xml. At the end of the makefile:

```
@echo "——————————————————————————————————"
@echo "  Results for Sparkle Update XML  "
@echo "——————————————————————————————————"
@echo
@echo "version:           " `defaults read myApp.app/Contents/Info CFBundleVersion`
@echo "shortVersionString:" `defaults read myApp.app/Contents/Info CFBundleShortVersionString`
@echo "dsaSignature:      " `$MyAppSource/Libraries/Sparkle/bin/sign_update myAppInstaller.pkg.zip $MyAppSource/Resources/UpdateSigningKeys/dsa_priv.pem`
@echo "length:            " `stat -f%z "myApp.pkg`
```