# Notarize a .zip file

Tags: macos, codesign

I am trying to write a script to notarize an app for distribution outside the Mac App Store. I have (in the past) successfully notarized a `.dmg` but for some reason I am running into trouble with a `.zip` file. The error I am receiving in the log file from notarization is that there is no code signature present.

So here is my notarization code:

```
cd app && zip MyZip.zip Test.app
cd -

xcrun altool --notarize-app \
   --file "app/Myzip.zip" \
   --username "abcabcabc" \
   --password "abcabcabc" \
   --asc-provider "abcabcabc" \
   --primary-bundle-id "a.b.c.com"
```

When I check to verify the code signature on the `Test.app`, it appears to be fine:

```
codesign -vvv --deep --strict app/Test.app
app/Test.app: valid on disk
app/Test.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

Running the same on the .zip file--as expected, returns an error:

```
codesign -vvv --deep --strict app/MyZip.zip
app/MyZip.zip: code object is not signed at all
```

Which is correct, as I did not sign the zip file. However, when I read other people's experiences, they seem to talk about uploading `.zip` files for notarization as if there is no problem (for example, steps 2 and 3 here: [What is the most efficient way to notarize and staple a .zip containing a .app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60608887/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-notarize-and-staple-a-zip-containing-a-app)). Has something changed since 2019--do I now need to manually use the `codesign` tool to sign my zip file using the same identity that the app is signed with? I even tried the following, as requested by Apple in the documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution/customizing_the_notarization_workflow):

```
/usr/bin/ditto -c -k --keepParent "app/Test.app" "app/MyZip.zip"
```

but running `codesign -vvv --deep --strict app/MyZip.zip` still returns `code object is not signed at all`.

Do I need to custom code sign? Or is there a way to zip it but somehow preserve the codesign signature? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me (just tested):

```
codesign --force \ 
   --timestamp \
   --options runtime \ 
   --sign "Developer ID Application: <USER> (<TEAMID>)" project1.app

zip -r test.zip project1.app

xcrun altool --notarize-app \
   --primary-bundle-id "com.company.project1" \
   -u "<EMAIL>" \
   -p "<PWD>" \ 
   -t osx \
   -f test.zip
```

As to what has changed since 2019: On 3 September 2019 Apple announced that until January 2020 developers could get new versions of applications notarized even though they were not hardened or fully compliant with the normal requirements. That deadline was later extended to 3 February 2020. After that, you need to meet all the prerequisites:

- Enable code-signing for all of the executables you distribute.
- Enable the Hardened Runtime capability for your application and command line targets.
- Use a “Developer ID” application, kernel extension, or installer certificate for your code-signing signature.
- Include a secure timestamp with your code-signing signature
- Don’t include the com.apple.security.get-task-allow entitlement with the value set to any variation of true.
- Link against the macOS 10.9 or later SDK.

Comment: The above answer from @Trev also works when the app is a command line tool (a Unix executable). Compile on the command line rather than in Xcode, then codesign the Unix executable as above and zip.  One thing I didn't understand was where the `--primary-bundle-id` comes from since a Unix executable isn't a bundle. Turns out, you just make up the bundle-id when you run `xcrun altool --notarize-app`.  The "<EMAIL>" is your apple-id and "<PWD>" is an application specific password that you create on the appleid.com site (not the Developer site).